# How do I "stick" and object or div to the top of another div?

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry for the basic question.

I have an image I want to attach the top right of a div, but I don't know how to accomplish this

Here's an image of the issue:

[image]

I would like to attach the "Flack" object to the top right of the white div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<object class="headerimage" data="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/flackH.svg') }}"></object>
  <div class="chatroom">
    <div id="contain">
      <div id="channels">
        <div class="list-group">
          <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">General</button>
          {% for channel in channels %}
          <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ channel }}</button>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="create-channel">
          <form class="channel-create">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="c" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Create a channel"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="chat">
        <ul id="messages">
          {% for dict in messages %}
            <li>{{dict.time}} - {{ dict.username }} : {{dict.message}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="input">
          <form id="send-message">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="m" class="form-control" autofocus="true" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Send a message"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSS `position` property.

By default, every HTML element has its `position` set to `static`. You can position an element relative to its enclosing parent by setting its `position` property to `absolute`. This will result in the element being automatically positioned at x=0, y=0 of its parent (meaning top-left). 
You can then move it around with the CSS properties `top/right/bottom/left`.

*Note that for this to work, you need to also change the `position` property of the parent from the default `static` to something like `absolute` or `relative`*

In your case, you need to bring the image inside the white div (which I assumed is the one with the id "chat") and say that it should position itself according to its parent.

**HTML**

```
<div class="chatroom">
    <div id="contain">
    <div id="channels">
        <div class="list-group">
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">General</button>
        {% for channel in channels %}
        <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ channel }}</button>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="create-channel">
        <form class="channel-create">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="c" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Create a channel"></div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
        <object class="headerimage" data="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/flackH.svg') }}"></object>
        <ul id="messages">
        {% for dict in messages %}
            <li>{{dict.time}} - {{ dict.username }} : {{dict.message}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="input">
        <form id="send-message">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="m" class="form-control" autofocus="true" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Send a message"></div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#chat {
    position: relative;
    /* Without this change, the class `headerimage` below will try to position
    itself according to its first parent that is not `position:static`.
    Since it won't find any, it will position itself according to the `body`.

    You prevent that by setting its immediate parent's positon to relative or absolute*/
}

.headerimage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* Give different values to top and right if you want some
    spacing from the borders */
}
```